# Using a UIImage as the application icon

Tags: cocoa-touch

Is possible to set an image as an iPhone application unique icon in code instead of adding a PNG format image file and naming it `Icon.png`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you would add to your Info.plist:

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>app.png</string>
```

This (as well as other related options) is well documented in the [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/chapter_3_section_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW16).

*Note: you may need an Apple Developer account to see that link*.

Answer (score 3):

a) No, not for developer applications. Also note that Apple's preload applications can demonstrably alter Default.png (see the Notes app) but that can't be done by the rest of us.

b) The app icon can also be a jpeg and can be called whatever you like - you just need to set it appropriately in Info.plist